# Жизненно-существенные — как правильно (раздельно или через дефис)?

Tags: орфография

Answer (score 1):

Помнится, у Розенталя есть такой пример: общественно полезный - полезный для общества. Отсюда и данный пример можно так же интерпретировать: жизненно существенный - существенный для жизни

Answer (score 0):

Это два слова.  
Если слово является термином или образовалось от словосочетания, то пишется слитно (1) вечнозеленый, 2) ремонтировать вагоны - вагоноремонтный, железная дорога - железнодорожный). Если от однородный членов (однородные не являются словосочетанием), то пишется через дефис. А если это слова отдаленные по смыслу (не являются ни словосочетанием, ни однородными), то пишутся в два слова.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, это некорректное словосочетание. Есть *жизненно важный*, *жизненно необходимый*, а *жизненно существенного*, кажется, нет. Даже *существенный для жизни* звучит подозрительно. Но могу ошибаться.

Comment: В Нацкорпусе одно вхождение есть, на дефисе. http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E6%E8%E7%ED%E5%ED%ED%EE+%F1%F3%F9%E5%F1%F2%E2*

Comment: Спасибо, а значит ли это, что выражение соответствует норме? Написание через дефис можно объяснить каким-то правилом?

Comment: Если эти два слова приняли за синонимы (существенный - от существую, жизненный - от живу), то по правилу, которое я описал выше, но, по-моему, глупо так делать.

Comment: Словарной фиксации этого сочетания я не нашла. Если нет в словаре, значит и нормой еще не стало. По второму вопросу: в словаре Букчиной Б. З. "Слитно, раздельно, через дефис" (2001) есть такое примечание "Допустимо двоякое написание (обычно в художественно-публицистических текстах) в зависимости от различного понимания сочетаний — как двух прилагательных или наречия и прилагательного. Ср. болезненно-навязчивая(мысль) и болезненно навязчивый..." То есть можно и так и так. (Кто там знает, какой смысл автор вкладывает.)

Comment: Согласна, автору может быть виднее. А правило интересное, спасибо. Но все равно не нравится мне это выражение, очень уж оно "авторское", что ли. Я бы рекомендовала его чем-то заменить. (Но это мое очень субъективное мнение.)

Answer (score 0):

Если это современное значение слова "существенный", то словосочетание, согласна с Инной, нужно писать раздельно,но оно некорректно, тавтологично: существенный-уже важный для жизни,составляющий суть, но есть устаревшее слово "существенный"-от "существо, живая особь".Тогда смысл сочетания слов меняется - появляется оттенок, поэтому пишется через дефис.
      Протоиерей Александр Шаргунов: "Фарисеи, до мелочей соблюдавшие предписания обрядовой чистоты, отодвигали на второй план жизненно-существенные отношения между людьми".
    Так что смотря в каком значении употреблено.